# How to pass correctly parameter from view to controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

```
<button class="card-link" asp-action="Edit" type="submit" 
        asp-for="editId" value=@cc.Id>
    Id: @cc.Id
</button>
```

The problem is that `editId` is always `0` though `@cc.Id` is not `0`

This is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit(int editId)
{
     Company co = db.Companies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == editId);
     return View(co);
}
```

[image]

Sorry for such a beginner's question, but I couldn't solve it myself

Comment: You either need an `<input type="hidden">` on your form `@Html.HiddenFor()` or need to pull the id from the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to pass correctly parameter from view to controller?

Actually, this can be implemented in numerous way. In other words, if you would like to stick with edit HttpPost method, you could use [Asp Form Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-7.0#the-form-tag-helper) and as you have parameter editId so you can pass it using [asp-route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-7.0#asp-route-value) in order to submit your request from view to controller.

In addition to this, if you can make your edit method as HttpGet than it will be much easier because you can simply pass  editId asp-route using button or anchor tag.

Let's have a look in practice how can we achieve that.

**Way: 1: Using Asp Form Tag Helper:**

Model:

```
public class ResponseViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } = 101;
    }
```

Index View:

```
@model Project.Models.ResponseViewModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit" method="post" asp-route-editId="@Model.Id">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit View:

```
<a asp-action="Edit" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-editId="555">Submit</a>

@if (TempData["Param"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        @TempData["Param"]
    </div>
}
```

Index Controller Action:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var response = new ResponseViewModel();
           
            return View(response);
        }
```

**Note:** Index controller action would remain same in either sceenario.

Edit Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Edit(int editId)
        {
            TempData["Param"] = editId;
            return View();
        }
```

**Way: 2: Using HttpGet and Asp-Route:**

In this scnario, you would require to modidy your Edit Method from HttpPost to HttpGet in order to make it simpler.

Let's take a look...

Index View:

```
@model ProjectName.Models.ResponseViewModel
<a asp-action="Edit" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-editId="@Model.Id">Submit</a>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Edit(int editId)
        {
            TempData["Param"] = editId;
            return View();
        }
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details [how to submit request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-7.0) you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `ActionLink` to achieve your functionality. First, remove your button logic completely and then specify the `ActionLink` that will generate the required HTML structure:

`@Html.ActionLink("Id: " +@cc.Id, "Edit", "{ControllerName}", new { editId = @cc.Id }, new { @class = "card-link" })`

Change your `POST` to `GET` in your `Controller`:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Edit(int editId)
{
     Company co = db.Companies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == editId);
     return View(co);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code(you use tag-helpers) have some problems

1.The use of the asp-for is something else, you used it wrong

asp-for attribute normally populate id and name of the specified HTML attribute for the display expression name. [aspnet-core-tag-helpers](https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/aspnetcore/aspnet-core-tag-helpers#:%7E:text=ASP.NET%20Core%20is%20an,web%20services%20and%20web%20applications.)

2.You used a direct link, Your action better is a Type get

If you want to send Post, use the form tag [form-tag](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/form-tag-helper-and-other-common-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc/)

```
 <form asp-action="Edit" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" value="@cc.Id" asp-for="@cc.Id" />
//Other your Tag(input ,..)
            <button class="card-link" type="submit"  value="Edit">
                Id: @cc.Id
            </button>

        </form>
```

3.If You want to create a link with the button, you must use the form

4.better ,you can use tag a for link [tag a](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

asp-route-id:Paramater route
asp-action:action

```
<a class="card-link" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@cc.Id">Edit</a>
```